# Original mysqldump file import: Cannot add foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging, datatable

This sql is from mysqldump file and it keeps give me: `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`
I have struggled for a whole afternoon for this inconsistency, still don't know what the problem really is.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `regions`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `regions` (
  `region_id` bigint(20) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `region_code` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_code` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`region_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ui_RegionCode` (`region_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `regions_ParentCode_RegionCode` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_code`) REFERENCES `regions` (`region_code`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3525 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: What MySQL is this? With 5.5.9 I got no problem.

Comment: I got 5.5.40-MariaDB on server and 5.6.20 on my local machine.

Comment: I had the same problem with a mysql dump from staging. The tables had the correct constraints as far as I can tell; finally resolved by removing all instances of `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4`. Not why that why getting "1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint"  thou.

Comment: I had same error on MySQL 5.7.8rc but removing all DEFAULT CHARSETs as @Ithar says help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "CONSTRAINT `regions_ParentCode_RegionCode` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_code`) REFERENCES `regions`" a self referencing on table regions.

Try to create you table without this statement

```
CREATE TABLE `regions`(
  `region_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `region_code` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_code` INT(6) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`region_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ui_RegionCode` (`region_code`)
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 3525 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

and add it after this with after this

```
ALTER TABLE regions
        ADD
        CONSTRAINT `regions_ParentCode_RegionCode`
        FOREIGN KEY (`parent_code`) REFERENCES `regions` (`region_code`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: I ran the the foreign-key-clean version and it still says `[HY000][1215] Cannot add foreign key constraint` -- my command doesn't even has a single word related to "foreign". What a MySQL-style message.